# 7 Increase the "Expires" header

Tags: 7, caching, .htaccess

I am trying to optimize a Drupal 7 site. I noticed the `Expires` header is set to just 6 hours, although according to my `.htaccess` file, it should be 2 weeks. Then i found out `mod_expires` module is not enabled. Now i have two questions:

1. Since i don't have the necessary rights, is there a way to set the `Expires` header without enabling `mod_expires`?
2. What is setting the header to 6 hours?

EDIT: Another strange thing is that the header is not there at all for some of the css files.

Also the settings in my `/admin/config/development/performance` is as follows, if related to this:

`Cache pages for anonymous users: checked
Cache blocks: checked
Minimum cache lifetime: none
Expiration of cached pages: 1 day`

Comment: /admin/config/development/performance?

Comment: `$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = ...` in settings.php maybe?

Comment: That value is not set

Comment: What do you want to have 2 week expires? Just files like images and css/js?

Comment: Yes. For the static files.

Comment: Is mod_headers available on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some boilerplate Apache rules I came up with for this question based off of the rules found in the [advagg](https://drupal.org/project/advagg) [readme](http://drupalcode.org/project/advagg.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt#l396). The inverted files match is untested but based off this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926604/inverted-filesmatch; got what needed to be excluded by looking at [core's](https://drupal.org/project/drupal) [.htaccess](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/.htaccess#l36)

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!\.php)$">
  # No mod_headers
  <IfModule !mod_headers.c>
    # No mod_expires
    <IfModule !mod_expires.c>
      # Use ETags.
      FileETag MTime Size
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Use Expires Directive.
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Do not use ETags.
    FileETag None
    # Enable expirations.
    ExpiresActive On
    # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
    ExpiresDefault A1209600
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Do not use etags for cache validation.
    Header unset ETag
    <IfModule !mod_expires.c>
      # Set a Cache-Control header to 2 weeks.
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, no-transform, public"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      Header append Cache-Control "no-transform, public"
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

In your case the best you can do is to use ETags.

Note: If you happen to be serving all you static file assets from a CDN then you could enable [far-future headers](https://drupal.org/project/cdn) in the CDN module. Doing it this way will route almost all static file traffic through PHP (on a origin request) so it can be extremely damaging to the sites performance if you are not using a CDN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but "ETag" headers are currently set actually. But that "Expires" header is annoying and Google Page Insight is complaining about it.

Comment: You are out of luck if you can not get mod_headers or mod_expires enabled on apache :(

Comment: Ok, thx. Do you have any idea what may be setting it to 6 hours?

Comment: Something up stream or Apache. Good luck